# Trying to get symbols for an iOS .crash file

Tags: xcode

I'm stumped on how to get symbols for a .crash file out of xcode.

I have the .crash file, the .app file, the .ipa file and the .dSYM file.  I drag the crash log into the xcode organizer and I see the crash log with symbols for system calls, but no symbols for my app.

The .app/.ipa was built by our build machine, so it was not archived via xcode.

I tried placing all three files (well, two are actually directories but look like files to the Mac) in the same folder and nothing.  I tried running symbolicatecrash from the command line while in that directory and I get this error:

```
Error: "DEVELOPER_DIR" is not defined at /Applications/Xcode.app/[snip]Resources/symbolicatecrash line 53.
```

I tried setting DEVELOPER_DIR to /Applications/Xcode.app and it gets further, but now I see a slew of errors that read:

```
sh: /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcrun: No such file or directory
```

I'm stumped.  You'd think this would be easier given all 4 needed files are in same directory.

I am running xcode 4.4, but was experiencing the same issues last night with 4.3.  I was hope upgrading would help.

Answer (score 63):

Make sure you set the right DEVELOPER_DIR:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Xcode is written with capital X. Tested on Mountain Lion (10.8).

Comment: On my Lion, Xcode has small c, not a capital one. As my partition is case sensitive, it is important.

Comment: Worked for me - I'm using Lion

Comment: "export DEVELOPER_DIR=\`xcode-select --print-path\`" should set the right path, no matter what version of Xcode you're running.

Comment: It's "Xcode." "XCode" works because the file system is case insensitive.

Comment: I just lost "Contents" "s" wwwwwwwwww

Answer (score 6):

First set correct Xcode location:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

I set this variable and got it working.

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then and I ran the symbolicatecrash in this directory:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources
```

Comment: For me, this solution worked but i had to
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

Comment: Still the same results: `sh: /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcrun: No such file or directory` and no symbols in the output.

Comment: @Roger try export DEVELOPER_DIR=/

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry my answer was written before properly reading your question).

Use [`xcode-select`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) to set the correct location of your Xcode install.  More precisely:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```