# Objective c-Symbolication issue Error: "DEVELOPER_DIR" is not defined at ./symbolicatecrash line 60

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Error shown in the terminal

```
:Resources myDirectory$ ./symbolicatecrash /foldername/myapp_2014-04-02-130024_Review-Machine.crash /foldername/myapp.app.dSYM

Error: "DEVELOPER_DIR" is not defined at ./symbolicatecrash line 60.
```

I was trying to symbolicate my app but this error is shown.I have read many of the tutorials about symbolication and gone through the way.Even someone had this same issue and the solution i have tried out ie,creating a new folder and adding the .app,.dSYM and crash files.

The foldername in the error is the new folder i have created.

But i still get this error.Is this way wrong??
I have even tried by symbolicating through Xcode by adding to Organiser but didn't work!!!!1

Anybody has any idea what is the problem here???Please help i am new to this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to get symbols for an iOS .crash file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682789/trying-to-get-symbols-for-an-ios-crash-file)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

add as a first line of your script that runs symbolicatecrash script:

> export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

By the way, you've copied symbolicatecrash script to some folder from it's initial location?

Comment: No i haven't copied the symbolicatecrash.Is that necessary? I have tried the line you have told.It goes well then if i try to symbolicate now its shows the errors there is no such file or directory                                                         while reading /foldername/myapp_2014-04-02-130024_Review-Machine.crash, No such file or directory : at ./symbolicatecrash line 668.    But the file is still in foldername

Comment: this is an absolute path, you should specify full path like /usr/username/folder_where_your_file_is/
or ~/folder_where_your_file_is

Comment: Thanks for your help @Andrei Shender.But the same error repeats :( any other way? I have heard that xcode automatically symbolicate and tried too but no idea..it didn't work..

Comment: You can also just add `$DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/';` to the script itself

Answer (score 6):

Follow two steps to find and export missing `DEVELOPER_DIR`

- Output of `xcode-select --print-path` on terminal is the value of `DEVELOPER_DIR`, something like, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
- Run the following command in the Terminal app, or insert into `~/.bashrc` if using Bash:
  `export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`